# flutter.io (dart) - how to hide keyboard suggestions bar?

Tags: keyboard, dart, flutter

In a Flutter app textBox, user is entering text and numbers. What method can be used to suppress the keyboard suggestion bar?

Comment: I wound up using "keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress".

Answer (score 3):

use **EditableText** class and set property **autocorrect** to **false**.
Do tell if it works, haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I tried out autocorrect on a TextField and it worked as expected.

Comment: This did not work for me. Suggestions bar still came up and stuck around.

Comment: I did use this though and upvoted because in this context autocorrect will also be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for disable sugestions and autocorrect:

```
TextField(
   enableSuggestions: false,
   autocorrect: false
),
```

Answer (score 0):

just add parameter autocorrect:false,Then it will hide the suggestions.

```
new TextField(
    autocorrect: false,
    controller: _tbName,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
       icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
       hintText: 'Enter your Name',
       labelText: 'Name',
       helperText: 'Required',
       errorText: nameErrorText,
    ),
    onChanged: (value) {
      //save here               
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the suggestion bar, you need to use the `smartDashesType` parameter.
This solution works fine for me:

```
TextFormField(
   smartDashesType: SmartDashesType.disabled,
   autocorrect: false
)
```